# Differences between "obwohl" and "obgleich" and when to use them?

Tags: word-choice, conjunction

Subordinating conjunctions always seem to raise the most questions for me, specifically in the differences between *obwohl* and *obgleich*. The text I am using in my studies states that they both mean "although," but when should I use one over the other? My text is not very clear on this and I'd like some sort of clarification to improve my German usage in the long-run.

Comment: Swiss people also use *"obschon"* which is even more confusing to people who aren't familiar with the word.

Comment: @splattne: Actually, I'd be more familiar with *obschon* than *obzwar* ;)

Comment: @splattne: the *only* person I've ever actually heard using "obschon" is [Gunkl](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%BCnther_Paal).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your *active* knowledge, just forget about "obgleich"; just use "obwohl" all the time – the basic meaning is the same. I actually don't know if I ever used "obgleich" in the spoken language (and I'm a native speaker).

Comment: @thei: I took me some time, but then I got it - you mean "aloud" when you write "allowed". And yes, poetry is _the_ exception (besides talking about the word "obgleich" `:-)`).

Comment: @Hendrik I am quite sure that I never used "obgleich" in speech or writing except when reading aloud some poetry. (What error? :))

Comment: Build your vocab, I say.  It's better to have a thesaurus (abridged, natch) in your head than having to fetch one from the bookshelf.  Granted, I don't think I ever used "obgleich", but I'm pretty sure I have used synonyms of "obwohl" sometimes (rarely, sure, but all the same)

Comment: @jae: I'm not sure what your point it. "Obgleich" is of course one of the synonyms of "obwohl" in the thesaurus in _my_ head, and I'm not advising the OP to wipe the word from _their_ passive knowledge. I guess I just don't get what you're writing `:-)`

Comment: I spoke with my professor and she echoed pretty much the same thing. She said that I would likely never hear "obgleich," but that if I wanted to ever use it, by all means do so. She is also a nerd when it comes to not frequently used German words and often encourages learning words that we wouldn't often hear.

Comment: @Sorcerer: Just be prepared for surprised looks if you use it!

Comment: @Hendrik Even when I meant to jokingly use it today I forgot, so chances are I will only use *obwohl*. I have a hard enough time having the courage to speak German out loud, much less using a word that would get strange looks!

Comment: @Sorcerer: I'd expect more _surprised_ than _strange_ looks. When I hear "obgleich", I'd expect it to come, e.g., from the mouth of a professor for philosophy or German `:-)`

Comment: Your answer should be written as:
"Obwohl is used in the actively spoken language, while obgleich is used more in writing and poetry.  You can use obgleich in spoken language if you want to surprise people with an indication that you have a desire for creativity, variation, and a deeper interest in the German language beyond everyday boring rhetoric."  

Dismissively asking people who seek knowledge to disregard valid, existing entries is NOT the best answer.

Comment: You can also use "obgleich" when you're roleplaying as a nobleman in a Pen&Paper RPG. It sounds theatrical.

Answer (score 9):

Both words are very similar in meaning, though *obgleich* may sound slightly more archaic to some. *Obwohl* seems to be younger. However, [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Adverbial/Konzessiv.html) lists these as meaning the same, while there are several other similar words that have an elevated connotation, like *obzwar*, *wenngleich*, *obschon* and *wiewohl*.

I think you hear *obwohl* more in everyday language, while *obgleich* is more used in written language.

Comment: Ngram Viewer says you're right: http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=obwohl%2Cobgleich%2Cobschon%2Cwenngleich%2Cwiewohl&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3

Comment: @splattne: I didn't bother looking this time. *Obgleich* is in the Grimm, *obwohl* isn't. Interesting though that NGrams shows that *obwohl* was already used in the end of the 18th century / beginning of 19th century... By the way, I added *obzwar* to the NGram, which is definitely less used.

Comment: I assume by "Grimm" you are referring to the fairy tales? If so, that definitely puts the archaic nature of *obgleich* into better perspective.

Comment: @Sorcerer Blob: I'm referring to the [DWB](http://dwb.uni-trier.de/Projekte/WBB2009/DWB/wbgui_py?lemid=GA00001), *Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm*, or just Grimmsches Wörterbuch or Grimm for short, which is by far the largest etymological work on the German language. Even though the brothers didn't finish it (it was actually only finished 1961), it's basically the same time as the fairy tales though.

Answer (score 2):

"Obgleich" is a more archaic and poetic version of the word. You won't hear it used outside of poems these days.