# Obwohl und seine Synonyme

Tags: word-choice, synonym

[Hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1369/differences-between-obwohl-and-obgleich-and-when-to-use-them) wurde *obwohl* und *obgleich* betrachtet. Jetzt stelle ich eine breitere Frage.

Es gibt viele Synonyme zu *obwohl: obgleich, obschon, obzwar* und *wenngleich*. Ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen nur der, dass sie mehr gehoben wirken als *obwohl*? Können sie im geschriebenen Text (z.B. Abhandlungen oder Aufsätze) gebraucht werden oder sind sie auch dazu zu veraltet? Sind sie heutzutage überall verwendbar?

Comment: Jeder Deutschlehrer würde Dich vermutlich ermuntern, für Abwechslung zu sorgen. Dennoch ist diese Frage nur hochgradig subjektiv zu beantworten. Mir persönlich ist es beispielsweise wurscht, ob "obschon" oder "obgleich" als veraltet betrachtet werden. Ich verwende sie dennoch.

Comment: I vote to leave this question open because it is not explicitly *asking* for the synonyms but rather asking if they are too old-fashioned *as a group*. That greatly reduces this question's broadness. Ich stimme dafür, diese Frage offenzulassen, da sie nicht explizit nach Synonymen frägt, sondern vielmehr wissen möchte, ob die Synonyme *in ihrer Gesamtheit* altmodisch wirken. Dadurch ist sie viel enger gestellt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl, das sich in diesem Fall mit dem Urteil meines 1991er Dudens deckt, ist *obzwar* veraltet, während *obgleich*, *obschon* und *wenngleich* unauffällig sind.